# Sending object to JS function not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I'm attempting to send an object from a react component to a JS function that calls an API, but for some reason the passing doesn't work and I can't figure out whats wrong.

Here's the line calling the function

updateHousingUnit({sessionKey}, company = {objectToSend});

and here's the first lines of the function receiving the object:

```
const updateCompanyDetails = ({sessionKey},{company}) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify("inside update " + company));
```

For whatever reason the it shows up as undefined in the console.log of the function while a log inside the react component before calling the function shows it storing all the data expected, I think this should be a syntax error, but I can't see what is making it not work?
I've tried using the spread(...) operator when calling the function as well without luck.

Comment: Your function definition is incorrect. Your parameters don't have names since you've wrapped them with braces. Remove the curly braces. Would look like `const updateCompanyDetails = (sessionKey, company) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Should work as intended. however please not that a function with this syntax `({someKey}) => someKey` applys destructuring to the passed argument. In this case `someKey` would be the same as `(arg) => arg.someKey`

```js
const updateCompanyDetails = ({
  sessionKey
}, {
  company
}) => {
  console.log(`company: '${company}', sessionKey: '${sessionKey}'`);
}


updateCompanyDetails({sessionKey: 'someKey'}, {company: 'someCompany'})
```